# How to temporarily disable iCloud Private Relay for a specific website on macOS with Safari?

Tags: macos, icloud, safari, privacy, icloud-plus

I know it's possible on iPadOS and iOS (source: [How to Temporarily Disable iCloud Private Relay for a Specific Website on iPhone and iPad](https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/temporarily-disable-icloud-private-relay-ios/)) but I can't find a way to do the same on Safari for macOS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On macOS, click and hold (or right click) the reload button and then choose "Reload and Show IP Address"